# Function template overloading: Stroustrup example understanding

Tags: c++

I've browsed a few threads with the same title as this but can't find anything that has helped me figure this out...

The following is a scan of a little example from "The C++ Programming Language", Second Edition, B Stroustrup, section 13.3.2 (page 336).

[image]

I don't understand the third `sqrt(z)` overload resolution. I expected that the resolution would have been `sqrt<complex<double>>(complex<double>)`.

Obv the function `double sqrt(double)` doesn't fit the bill. But I also thought `template<class T>T sqrt(T)` couldn't be resolved to `sqrt<double>(complex<double>)` as this seems to me to imply `T` has two different resolutions which I would have thought it can't... `T` must be the same thing throughout it's "scope".

Is there something I have misunderstood and could you point it out? :) Thanks!

Comment: Look at the decl closely. there is a difference between the type in the template argument (`T`) and the type of the parameter (`complex<T>`). The latter pulls it's `T` from the former. Thus, his notation is correct. Or. . I totally misunderstood your question (not unlikely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one is a speciallization wich fits the call. The parameter is T, that is, the type in

```
complex<T>
```

then the function is

```
sqrt<double>
```

Remember that the compiler selects the most speciallized template function.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, as you've spotted, there are two possible ways to match the signature to a template. The first template `template<class T> T sqrt(T)` could be matched. Having `T` equal to `complex<double>` makes a function (a template specialization) with the signature `complex<double> sqrt(complex<double>)`.

The second template `template<class T> complex<T> sqrt(complex<T>)` could also be matched. In this case, setting `T` to `double` makes a specialization with the same signature as the specialization of the first template.

Template overload resolution chooses the more specialized template: in this case, the one that only works on `complex<T>`. If it helps make it easier to understand, you might rename the `T` to something else in the second template: the templates are like:

```
template<class T> T sqrt(T);
template<class U> complex<U> sqrt(complex<U>);
```

This way, it's easier to see that the template parameters are unrelated in the two function templates. You can get `complex<double>` by either an appropriate choice for `T` or an appropriate choice for `U`, and the second template is more specialized.

Comment: Thanks Dan, this also helped :) I've accepted Antonio's answer, although it is less thorough in some ways, as it made the penny drop for me.